# Center a mobile site that's larger than the viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, center, viewport

I've been provided with a mobile site design that's `790px` wide but the content is centered in a 392px wide `<div>`.
I'd like to have this centered on mobile devices (i.e. iphone) but when it loads presently, the center div is off to the right - I essentially want the site to center around the center div, if you know what I mean. The structure is currently like this:

stylesheet

```
html, body, form, fieldset, p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

viewport code in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=.7, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

code in the page (sample)

```
<div align="center">
<div style="width: 790px;">
<img src="images/image.png" width="790" height="136" border="0" />
<div style="width: 392px; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 26px;">
Center column content
</div>
<img src="images/image.png" width="790" height="136" border="0" />
</div>
</div>
```

It looks fine at the moment but I just want the phone to center around the content so the user doesn't have to swipe to the left.

Any help greatly appreciated!